# C: Is array element referencing compiler implementation specific?

Tags: c, arrays, pass-by-reference

Often I see the following syntax being used for C array element referencing:

```
int someArray[10];
(void*) a = &someArray[x];
```

this seems to increment the address by sizeof(int) with some compilers (e.g. mingw) and by sizeof(void*) with others (texas instruments).

Changing it to `(void*) a = &(someArray[x])` seems fixing this.

Where's the catch?
Is the precedence of "&" and "[x]" undefined by the standard?
What's the best practice for portable code?

Thanks!
Randolf

Comment: Given that `(void*) a = &someArray[x];` is not valid I doubt you see that that often.

Comment: right, sorry, I was trying to be figurative. What I meant is 
void *a;
int someArray[10];
a = &someArray[x];

or

someFunction(&someArray[x])

Comment: Post a real (not figurative) example that demonstrates the problem. The parentheses won't make a difference.

Comment: Interestingly enough, gcc up to 3.x had a [*generalized lvalues*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Lvalues.html) extension. The above would be interpreted as `(void *)(a = &someArray[x])`. No longer supported by gcc 4 and above, fortunately. And yes, `[]` has higher preference than `&`. If the compiler does it differently, the compiler is broken.

Comment: Please show what you directly observe (i.e. here's a self-contained program, here's its output on platform A, here's its output on platform B).

Comment: Will do but wait a bit - need to get to a computer with the Code Composer Studio license and it's in use at the moment. The non-standard behavior was observed with Code Composer Studio on the OMAP DSP platform. The CCS manual doesn't specify the precedence of the subscript operator. Maybe it's really just a non-standard compiler. We also have a feeling that the behavior could be related to the memory alignment. I will post the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with this code:

```
int someArray[10];
void *a = &someArray[x];
```

Proper compiler will increment pointer basing on sizeof(someArray[0]).

Probably, you should ask not about 'how to write portable code', but *how to write code which will work properly even when compiled with a wild compiler*...